# JQuery Toggle InputBox based on if another Inputbox has value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a page that contains two input boxes. I need one input box to disappear and then reappear depending on if there is a value in the other one. I've read that using JQuery is the easiest way to do this however I have limited experience with it and can't find documentation on how to implement this. Here is the page:

```
<label asp-for="Subject" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" id="Subject"/>

<label asp-for="Header" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="Header" class="form-control" id="Header"/>
```

Here is the JQuery I have so far from my limited knowledge. The input box is gone at the start.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Subject").val(function () {
    $("#Header").toggle(this.length > 0);
});
```

I am not sure how to implement this where writing text in one textbox will make the other one disappear. The debugger is not supplying any error messages about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the "Header" when the user has typed something in the "Subject"-input:

```
$("#Subject").on("input", function () {
   $("#Header").toggle(!!$(this).val().length);
});
```

You should also add `style="display: none;"` to the header to initially hide it.

Alternatively you could trigger the 'input' event manually once:

```
$("#Subject").on("input", function () {
   $("#Header").toggle(!!$(this).val().length);
}).trigger("input");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I accidentally put in the JQuery for a button and a text field. I updated the Script to what I currently have. Basically it's kind of the same concept except this one is two text fields where one should hide after text is entered in the other one. If the text is removed then both textboxes should be on the screen again. Again, Thank you so much for the help and you helped me with the button issue : )

Comment: In that case you should change the code to `$("#Header").toggle(!$(this).val().length);`

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#Subject").on("input", function() {
  let $e = $("#Header");
  $(this).val() == "" ? $e.addClass("hidden"): $e.removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label asp-for="Subject" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" id="Subject"/>

  <label asp-for="Header" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="Header" class="form-control hidden" id="Header"/>
</body>

</html>
```